# Multiple click action in mixed up mode [jQuery]

Tags: jquery

I have x3 video divs with x3 play divs within them. Is there any way whenever I click on any of those video divs, so the video which i've clicked triggers. Here is what I mean by code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('.play').click(function () {
    video = '<iframe style="margin-left:130px; margin-bottom:50px;" width="600" height="375" frameborder="0" src="' + $('img').attr('data-video') + '"></iframe>';
    $('.video').replaceWith(video);
});

$('.play2').click(function () {
    video2 = '<iframe style="margin-left:70px;margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px;" width="720" height="450" frameborder="0" src="' + $('img').attr('data-video') + '"></iframe>';
    $('.video2').replaceWith(video2);
});

$('.play3').click(function () {
    video3 = '<iframe style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px;" width="864" height="540" frameborder="0" src="' + $('img').attr('data-video') + '"></iframe>';
    $('.video3').replaceWith(video3);
});
```

});

**The problem is:** I have to click in a row of each of them to trigger.
And i'd like when I click in any of them to trigger. When I do that, sadly always the first one triggers instead of this which i've clicked.
Thanks!

**EDIT:
Here is the html code:**

```
<div class="video">
 <div class="play"><i class="icon-play"> ► </i>
 </div>
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9EcjYs8.jpg" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OgAr66JbvtU?autoplay=1"/>
</div>
<div class="video2">
 <div class="play2"><i class="icon-play"> ► </i>
 </div>
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IJAtO44.jpg" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bg4cdmrUPoQ?autoplay=1"/>
</div>
<div class="video3">
 <div class="play3"><i class="icon-play"> ► </i>
 </div>
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zPWy2ME.jpg" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mjwHO1b_tbE?autoplay=1"/>
</div>
```

I am assuming i should prolly add an ID of the img so each data-video might be triggered from the jQuery separately but idk, really.
Thanks, again.

Comment: Can you show your markup? At the minute, your `$("img")` selector pulls back all images on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside your onclick handler, you have this code:

`$('img').attr('data-video')`

That will always evaluate to the same thing (regardless of which element you clicked)

I am assuming you probably want something like this:

`$(this).attr('data-video')`

This assumes that `.play`, `.play2` and `.play3` are the img elements.

Further, you should probably use jQuery's data API and use this:

`$(this).data('video')`

If you're going to use jQuery, you might as well use all of it's features to make your life easier.

**EDIT**

There's a few ways I could describe that would allow you to fix this, but the easiest way is for you just to put the data-video attribute on the `<div class="play">` elements.

Easiest way for you to fix this is to put the data-video attribute on the

Comment: I tried but somehow it didn't work (pretty sure i am doing something wrong). However, I renewed the topic, please take a look of it :)